# How to change the group position of an Add-in inserted into a default office tab?

Tags: ms-word, manifest, office-js, office-addins

I have created an Office Add-In for Word, and the icon is placed into the [Insert tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/officetab#word), but by default it is in the very last position on the ribbon. I want my group to be placed in the first position of the tab, before Pages (this appears to be the first group by default). Is there something I can add into the manifest XML file to place the group at the start of the tab?

My manifest file currently looks something like this:

```
...
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
  <OfficeTab id="TabInsert">
    <Group id="MyCompany.MainGroup">
      <Label resid="MyCompany.MainGroup.Label" />
      <Icon>
        ...
      </Icon>
      <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyCompany.ActionButton">
        <Label resid="MyCompany.ActionButton.Label" />
        ...
      </Control>
    </Group>
  </OfficeTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
...
```

I would imagine that if this is possible, there should be something I can add underneath the `Group` element, but I don't see anything relevant in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/group). On the other hand, absence from the documentation doesn't mean it doesn't exist, since the `Icon` element is not listed there either, and without it my Add-In doesn't load.

The other element I can imagine a suitable option would exist is on the `ExtensionPoint` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint)), but I don't see anything suitable there either.

Comment: You could try adding 'insertBeforeMso="GroupInsertPages" to your group definition.

Comment: @Freeflow this didn't work unfortunately. I added it here: <Group id="MyCompany.MainGroup" insertBeforeMso="GroupInsertPages">

Comment: Then its likely you'll need to create a tab in the customxml used at word startup.  Make this tab hidden and provide the appropriate callbacks then your addin can 'take over' the hidden tab by responding to its callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The add-in buttons would always come after the default office ribbon controls. The only way where you can insert them at the beginning of the line would be to create a [custom tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/customtab).

Comment: @mft25 - Does this answer your question?